# Send Custom Events to Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is it possible to send custom action name instead of "purchase" . I read the whole documentation but couldn't find anything.

[image: Google Analytics Example]

Comment: Please share at least the code as text (not image) and what you(ve already tried. thx.

Comment: You can do an additional event tracking call, but since the actionField tells EEC about the intended action you cannot change it (and still expect your purchases to be tracked). What is it that you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Outside of GA ecomm, you can customise the names of anything if that makes it easier to work with whatever ecomm system you're using (ie. "buy" instead "purchase", or "sku" instead of "id"), but at the end of the day you *must* map back those names to whatever GA uses which, as @EikePierstorff mentioned, cannot be changed.